# Encoding problems with exec

Tags: php, character-encoding

I'm fetching some info from SVN on an internal webpage for our company using exec and SVN log commands. The webpage is ISO-8859-1 by requirement, but the SVN-server/exec outpu is UTF8 and special characters are decimal encoded not the "normal" encoding.

This makes it impossible to use UTF8_decode or similar function as far as I've been able to tell, and I can't really get the grips on exactly how the return is formatted otherwise str_replace would have worked as an workaround for the moment. For instance as far as i can see ä is represented by ?\195?\164, but I cant find and replace that string in the output so probably there are some other things going on that I'm missing

My SVN-server is a CentOS and the webserver is Debian running Apache if the culprit can be there somwhere

Pseudocode

```
exec('svn log PATH' , $output);
foreach ($output as data){
    $data = str_replace(array('?\195?\165', '?\195?\182'), array('å','ö'), $data);
    echo $data . '<br>';
}

foreach ($output as data){
    $data = utf8_decode($data);
    echo $data . '<br>';
}

foreach ($output as data){
    $data = mb_convert_encoding($data, 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8');
    echo $data . '<br>';
}
```

Example string echoed is "Buggfix f?\195?\182r 7.1.34" but should be "Buggfix för 7.1.34"

Comment: interesting...  do you get different results with the `mb_convert_encoding()` function?  it has wider options that you may be able to leverage.

Comment: No, it is exactly the same there and it is quite frustrating. Updated my question to reflect this